# TFS Get Latest Log

Tags: tfs

I ran a Get Latest... command in TFS and it pulled down a bunch of files that weren't current in my workspace. My problem is that I have no idea how to tell which files it pulled down.

Can someone point me to a location where I can see what files TFS retrieved from my most recent Get Latest... operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in visual studio select View->Output from the menu, then in the drop down box "show output from" select "source control - tfs"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a command for this but you could look at the Commit History in TFS to see what changed since the last commit. It's usually good practice to look at the history before getting latest version to know what has changed and what you are about to update.